# OpenLayer's VectorSource only adding first feature of array

Tags: openlayers, geojson, angular

I'm working on an angular implementation of OpenLayers:
the component receives a `Map` instance and a `Feature[]` observable. The component attaches the `Map` instance to the view and after doing so, it subscribes to the `Features[]` stream and adds it to the map. Right now it receives 5 random triangles.

After correctly initializing the Map, I run this code:

```typescript
this.featuresSubscription = this.features$.subscribe(features => {
      if (this.vectorLayer) {
        this.map.removeLayer(this.vectorLayer)
      }
      this.features = features.map(feature => new GeoJSON().readFeature(feature,  { featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857' }));
      this.vectorSource = new VectorSource({
        features: this.features
      })
      this.vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
        source: this.vectorSource,
        style: this.style
      })
      this.map.addLayer(this.vectorLayer)
    })
```

However, only the first feature in the array is added to the vector source. I've tried using the `vectorSource.addFeature()` on each element and again, only the first one gets added and the rest are ignored.

[image: Map with only one feature instead of five]

Checking with `vectorSource.getFeatures()`, I get `[Feature]` with only the first feature on the array.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working at last.
It seems that the issue was the recreation of the `GeoJSON` object to create single features.

Creating a single `GeoJSON` object and using its `readFeatures` method with the type `FeatureCollection` to parse the entire array of features at once worked.

Here's the working code:

```typescript
   this.featuresSubscription = this.features$.subscribe(features => {
      if (this.vectorSource) {
        this.map.removeLayer(this.vectorLayer)
      }
      const geojson = new GeoJSON({featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'});
      this.features = geojson.readFeatures({
        type: 'FeatureCollection',
        features: features
      });
      this.vectorSource = new VectorSource({
        features: this.features,
      })
      this.vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
        source: this.vectorSource,
        style: this.style,
        visible: true,
      })
      this.map.addLayer(this.vectorLayer)
    })
```